# Django: Save cleaned_data in a session effectively

Tags: django, forms, session, cleaned-data

In one of my forms, I am processing the form data and save it in a session variable.

So when I run

```
if locationForm.is_valid():
```

I execute

```
request.session['streetNumber'] = locationForm.cleaned_data['streetNumber']
request.session['postalCode'] = locationForm.cleaned_data['postalCode']
request.session['state'] = locationForm.cleaned_data['state']
request.session['country'] = locationForm.cleaned_data['country']
```

But this seems very inefficient.
I have tried

```
request.session = locationForm.cleaned_data
```

but it does not seem to work.

- Is there any better way of storing all cleaned_data information in a session variable?
- Are there security concerns I should be aware off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about

```
for k, v in locationform.cleaned_data.iteritems():
  session[ k ] = v
```

Comment: Note `iteritems()` is dead and you can use `items()` now