# Object does not support item assignment error

Tags: python, django, loops, dictionary

In my `views.py` I assign values before saving the form. I used to do it the following way:

```
projectForm.lat = session_results['lat']
projectForm.lng = session_results['lng']
```

Now, since the list of variables got a bit long, I wanted to loop over `session_results` with the following loop (as described by Adam [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454000/django-save-cleaned-data-in-a-session-effectively)):

```
for k,v in session_results.iteritems():
    projectForm[k] = v
```

But I get the error `'Project' object does not support item assignment` for the loop solution. I have trouble to understand why. `Project` is the model class, which I use for the ModelForm.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The error seems clear: model objects do not support item assignment.
`MyModel.objects.latest('id')['foo'] = 'bar'` will throw this same error.

It's a little confusing that your model instance is called `projectForm`...

To reproduce your first block of code in a loop, you need to use `setattr`

```
for k,v in session_results.iteritems():
    setattr(projectForm, k, v)
```

Answer (score 34):

Another way would be adding **__getitem__**, **__setitem__** function

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return getattr(self, key)
```

You can use self[key] to access now.

Answer (score 0):

> in my case i want render the data without _content but response object
> not editable or deletable so used vars which is now a dict not
> Response and removed prop _content

```
data_obj = vars(r)
del data_obj['_content']
data_json = json.dumps(data_obj, indent=4, default=str)
return data_json
```

Errors SEO:

> TypeError: 'Response' object does not support item deletion
>
> TypeError: 'Response' object does not support item assignment